# Line height button issue on Android?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

current styles on button:

```
.styles {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0.4rem 0.4rem;
    line-height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

on mobile the line height on the buttons seems off (see image)

any idea on what is causing this?

here is what it looks like: https://ibb.co/f2WYrK

Thanks

Comment: "mobile" is not a HTML engine. Which browser(s), versions etc? Also please show the related HTML. Any other styles applied to the button at the same time? What would you prefer it to look like? I assume you want the text to be vertically centred, but you didn't actually say what you perceive the issue to be. I assume you've tested on a variety of desktop browsers and not found a problem on any of them? Or you've only tested specific ones? Again it's not clear.

Comment: Please post a working fiddle or something.. So that everybody can easily have a look on it.

Comment: @ADyson sorry for not being very specific - it's on Android Google Chrome, also happens with Samsung Internet. Please see the screenshot for an idea of what it looks like as cannot replicate in JSFiddle which makes me think it may be an issue with the font? The font is currently being imported as a font-face through the css.